# how can i make my code show this output im new to smfl and codeblock

Tags: c++, sprite, sfml

**how can i make my code show this output im new to smfl and codeblock
i dont know how to call sprite and make it move
me and my friend are confuse during this pandemic online classes are hard :(**

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2GY1.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>


class Game
{
    public:Game();
        void             run();

    private:
        void processEvents();
        void update(sf::Time deltaTime);
        void render();
        void handlePlayerInput(sf::Keyboard::Key key,bool isPressed);

    private:
        sf::RenderWindow mWindow;
        sf::CircleShape  mPlayer;
        bool mIsMovingUp = false;
        bool mIsMovingDown = false;
        bool mIsMovingLeft = false;
        bool mIsMovingRight = false;
        float PlayerSpeed = 10.0f;
        sf::Time TimePerFrame = sf::seconds(1.f / 60.f);
};

Game::Game()
: mWindow(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML Application")
, mPlayer()
{
    mPlayer.setRadius(40.f);
    mPlayer.setPosition(100.f, 100.f);
    mPlayer.setFillColor(sf::Color::Cyan);
}
```

here is the link to the full code https://pastebin.com/g4v2DzgF
**PLEASE SEND HELP S.O.S**

Comment: What does your current code show? Also we usually want a minimal example however the code you present here does not attempt to solve the problem you want solved. It appears the full code on the link does attempt to solve the problem. Perhaps you simplified the code too much.

Comment: my current output is just the cyan color ball i want to make it as shown in the picture with the sprite please excuse my english it is not my first language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to load the texture.

```cpp
sf::Texture texture;
texture.loadFromFile("ship.png");
```

Do not delete the texture. It has to exist for you to use it.

Next you need to create a sprite using the texture.

```cpp
sf::Sprite sprite(texture);
```

Remember to draw the sprite, this is done in the same way you draw the player.

You can also move the sprite the same way you move the player.

Check out the documentation for more details:

- Drawing sprites:

  - https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-sprite.php
  - https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Texture.php
  - https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Sprite.php
- Moving transformables:

  - https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-transform.php
  - https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Transformable.php